# Required Payload

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have a Post method in my webapi project, lie the following:

```
public class BusinessesController: ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Business model) 
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
          return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        /*do stuff*/

        return Accepted();
    }
}
```

If i decorate the Business class with Attributes, those get validated, but if I pass a null payload, ModelState.IsValid returns true.

**TL;DR:** how do I send a bad request via data annotations if the parameter for the body is null?

Comment: Theoretically, could you just do `if (model == null || !ModelState.IsValid)`?

Comment: Just seams weird you can have Required attributes, but nothing the the payload variables, right?